# CSS3 gradient border around div with corner radius

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a thick border, 40px, around a div that has corner radius of 32px on each corner and then gradient fades out toward the center. Not sure if that's the best way to explain it, so I made a jsFiddle that tried to emulate what I need, but it's off.

http://jsfiddle.net/c7uYh/

```
there's too much code to post on here neatly.
```

**EDIT** When you look at the output of the jsFiddle, you'll see that the corners don't match the gradient of the sides, top and bottom. There's an obvious edge visible.

How can I get it to match?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

I'd just just box shadow instead too much nonsense to deal with....
Why wont there be option to tell gradient to follow shape. >>>(?)<<<<<
And however border gradients work..

-*_*-

http://jsfiddle.net/HwCyf/1/

```
div{
    display:inline-block;

}
#m {
    box-shadow:0 0 60px 35px white;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    margin:36px; border-radius:20px; 
    background-color:white;}

#b {
    background-color:rgb(231, 105, 255);
    border-radius:30px; border:1px solid purple;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's actually pretty close.